# How do I get the ESModules working in node.js (import/export) with babel

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So I've been adviced that I should use babel.js to transpile my code in order to use the import/export syntax. What I did is I followed the main setup guide that is at this link: https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

I created a `.babelrc` file after running `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` with this content:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {
      "allowTopLevelThis": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Well, I still keep getting the same error regardless :

```
import {Config} from '../config/config';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Here is my project structure :

[image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/-SBy9lF3T3mLhZ4uUNSYlQ.png]

I would really appreciate some help since I am out of ideas, thank you

Comment: How do you launch babel transpiling ?

Comment: that's my problem, i have configured it but I am unable to do anything with it. how am i supposed to alunch it?